# Root mean square distance explanation

Tags: probability, random-walk, standard-deviation

We know that $D_{rms}=\sqrt N$  where $N$ is the number of steps taken by the random walker.

Now,consider a situation where a random walker walks $2$ steps in positive direction in the first two steps.

So,the $D_{rms}=\sqrt2\approx1.41$.

But the actual distance is $2$ units.

So why are the two values different? I am really a beginner in this field, so a detailed explanation is very useful.

Comment: If you know the first two steps of a random walker, it's no longer a random walker. You cannot compute the rms distance with the formula that is used if you don't know the first two steps.

Comment: @HansEngler Is it *if you don't know the first two steps* or is it **if you know the first two steps**....did you have a typo there?

Comment: The formula is a particular kind of average over all possible walks of length $N$. You found _one_ of the walks that make up the average, but you need to average in all the others as well. Some of them have $D=0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are four equally probable possibilities for the first two steps of this random walk:

- positive, positive: $D=+2$
- positive, negative: $D=0$
- negative, positive: $D=0$
- negative, negative: $D=-2$

so the square root of the mean of the squares of these is $\sqrt{\dfrac{4+0+0+4}{4}}=\sqrt{2}$ as expected.  But this is before you know what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your two phrases "2 steps in positive direction in the first two steps", and "random walker".

How many steps does the walker need to take before it becomes "random"? Maybe 1000 **random** steps? This is more a problem of statistics/probability: how many samples do you need to get a certainty of a specified amount.

In your case, the answer 1.41 is correct, within the probability function. I.e. it will never be exactly 1.41, but it is likely that it is 1.41 ± X. (**EDIT**: For two steps, X = some number.) As the number of **random** steps increase, X decreases.

Comment: How do you say $X$ =1?

Comment: Before the walk, there's a 50% chance that $D=0$ after two steps, which is not within $1.41\pm1.0$. What is $X$?

Comment: Absolutely right. I have updated by answer